# 100% response rate with Amazon Elastic LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, load-balancing

as I understand, Load Balancer, like amazon elastic load balancer, or Google load balancer, they make health check. And decide to which instance forward the request.

The question is. One of my clients, send a request to get a list of 100 rows, from a table. In the middle of the request, the server stop responding. (For example I just push an update to the app, *or the app exited becuase of uncaught exception in the app source code* )

Can I use load balancer, to route the traffic to other instance (e.g. ec2), for respond?

In other words. If I want to make a service, that ALWAYS works. I believe that load-balancer, can't help. Because of something happened after the request forwarded, it will not be solved.

Comment: You would want to use connection draining to stop sending requests to an instance, and then remove that instance from the pool before doing something like pushing an update. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-conn-drain.html

Comment: It help only if I push update. But if the app just exit in the middle (uncaught exception witohut trry{}catch{} ). the user who send the request will not get any response

Comment: If you app fails during the request, then the users client will get that failure.  If you see this happening a lot then you should focus on making your client more resilient and have it verify the results of the request, then retry if needed

Comment: I am writing a backend API. Other user developing the clients. About 5 requests a day, got failure response. I am searching for a way to solve it.
Maybe what I need is to develop load-balancer by myself, the check success response

Comment: Add try/catch to your application? Your load balancer isn't going to solve this issue for you.

Comment: Do you know about solution that can solve app fall down, without changing the code?

Comment: No, you will have to design your application and infrastructure to handle that. There is no magic bullet to handle your server failing mid-request.